# /usr/bin/less from zsh 5.0.2

Tags: python, zsh, pyenv, less-unix

I wonder if this is only my case that
when I use `less` 458 (POSIX regular expressions),
`~/.zshenv` is read.

Because I use `pyenv` and `python` is in a directory of `pyenv` (PATH is set in ~/.zshrc),
`less` does not work.
The error message is 'no python is available.'.

If I explicitly set, at the top of `.zshenv`, `PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH`,
then `less` works.

Could  you explain what is going on...

Comment: Could you post the output of `echo $PATH` before modifying it?

Comment: Thank you
/home/kensuke/.pyenv/shims:/home/kensuke/.pyenv/bin:/home/kensuke/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/openmpi/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/local/sac/bin:/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux:/usr/local/evalresp/bin:/usr/local/TauP-2.3.0/bin:/usr/local/netcdf/bin:/home/kensuke/bin:/home/kensuke/.Kibrary/bin

.pyenv seems to be a reason.

Comment: And result of 'which less'? You could add it to the question as that is easier to read. I believe that there is a program in one of the directories before '/usr/bin' in PATH also called 'less'.

Comment: which less > /usr/bin/less and if I use it, I have the same error....

Comment: if less doesnt read .zshenv file, it works....

Comment: So I assume that 'which less' gives different results with and without reading .zenv? Post the contents of '.zenv'.